# Quiero optimizar un código con un bucle for para cambiar propiedades a botones

Tags: java, android, android-studio

He empezado un curso para `Android Studio` con Java. Durante el desarrollo de una "app ejercicio" en clase nos hicieron escribir esto:

```
    RadioButton btn_resp1 = findViewById(R.id.btn_resp0);
    btn_resp1.setText(pregunta.getResp()[0]);

    RadioButton btn_resp2 = findViewById(R.id.btn_resp1);
    btn_resp2.setText(pregunta.getResp()[1]);

    RadioButton btn_resp3 = findViewById(R.id.btn_resp2);
    btn_resp3.setText(pregunta.getResp()[2]);

    RadioButton btn_resp4 = findViewById(R.id.btn_resp3);
    btn_resp4.setText(pregunta.getResp()[3]);
```

¿Se puede optimizar (reducir la cantidad de código) este código con un bucle for para no tener que escribir 4 veces prácticamente lo mismo?

Comment: Por poder creo que se puede, pero te vas a complicar mucho para 4 líneas de código. Ya que tendrías que meter los objetos en un array y los id en otro array.

Comment: No necesita crear ningún array, se puede evaluar todo, lo único que busca es asignar textos a estos elementos. Simplemente hay que definir cuantos elementos se tienen para definirlos en el bucle. @ArnauAlloza

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No necesitas crear arreglos de botones, tampoco arreglos para los textos que agregaras a los `RadioButton` ya que los textos en realidad se contienen en el `array`:

```
pregunta.getResp()
```

De acuerdo a esto puedes realizar un bucle, evaluar los `RadioButton` mediante [**getIdentifier()**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) y posteriormente asignarles el texto almacenado en el array (`pregunta.getResp()`):

```
RadioButton btn_resp;
for(int i=0 ; i <5; i++){
    //Obtiene el id del widget.
    int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("btn_resp" +i, "id", getPackageName());
    //Obtiene la instancia.
    btn_resp = (RadioButton)findViewById(resourceId);
    //Define el texto al RadioButton.
    btn_resp.setText(pregunta.getResp()[i]);
 }
```

El ejemplo anterior es para que entendieras que es lo que se realiza, ahora de acuerdo a lo anterior **puedes reducirlo a simplemente este bucle**:

```
for(int i=0 ; i <5; i++){
    ((RadioButton)findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier("btn_resp" +i, "id", getPackageName()))).setText(pregunta.getResp()[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Como ya te comentaron se puede lograr con un arreglo.

Declara un array con tus botones:

```
private RadioButton[] arrRadioBotones = new RadioButton[4];
```

En `onCreate` inicializalos con un `for`:

```
for(int i=0; i<arrRadioBotones.length; i++){
        arrRadioBotones[i] = findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier("btn_resp"+(i+1), "id", getPackageName()));
    }
```

Nota que en getIdentifier el primer parámetro es el "id de tus botones" entonces concatenamos el nombre **"bt_resp" + (i+1)** para así obtener el id completo (bt_resp1, btResp2... etc)

Comment: Aunque es buena respuesta, a esto le llamaría yo "reducir el código", NO "optimización" ya que realmente no se optimizó nada y al contrario se hizo más difícil de entender a simple vista y por consecuencia de darle mantenimiento en el futuro.

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que deseas es un bucle puedes usar asi:

```
    for(int i; i<pregunta.getResp().length; i++){
        switch(i){
            case 0:
                ((RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.btn_resp0)).setText(pregunta.getResp()[i]);
            case 1:
                ((RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.btn_resp1)).setText(pregunta.getResp()[i]);
            case 2:
                ((RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.btn_resp2)).setText(pregunta.getResp()[i]);
            case 3:
                ((RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.btn_resp3)).setText(pregunta.getResp()[i]);
        }
    }
```

Igual puedes colocar todos los Id's de los componentes en un array.

```
        int[] ids = new int[]{R.id.R.id.btn_resp0, R.id.R.id.btn_resp1, R.id.R.id.btn_resp2, R.id.R.id.btn_resp3};
        for (int i; i<pregunta.getResp().length; i++) {
            ((RadioButton)findViewById(ids[i])).setText(pregunta.getResp()[i]);
        }
```